# Android app icon on top left when the app is in background state

Tags: android, android-icons

Is it possible to change this icon (screenshot)?
By default it is the standard launcher app icon. I do not want change my launcher icon, only this top-left launcher icon.
I already tried some stuff with Window.CORNER_LEFT etc. but this is for the Action/Title bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's the launcher icon. In order to change it, you'd have to [open up the Image Asset Studio by right-clicking the res directory -> New -> Image Asset](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html), and then configure the icon from there.

Comment: Thank you. And yes it is the launcher icon, but I try to change this icon only on the top left not the whole launcher icon.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible... Think of the launcher icon as the general app/software icon just like all the other (if not every) software out there.

Comment: Okay thank you Dave. I expected that it is not changeable. I have to redesign it. (Because the background of the top bar fits the background of the launcher icon - looks ugly).